# Mixing Legacy and UEFI boot - WIndows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I just installed Windows 7 on an MBR disk (SSD). I tried GPT, but there were a lot of issues.
Now, I am unable to boot from Ubuntu USB in Legacy BIOS so I booted in UEFI mode.

When I am trying to install Ubuntu and select manual partition, should I install it in /dev/sda or /dev/sda1 (which is a small ext4 partition I had reserved for boot.)

I cannot designate the partition as boot, only efi boot option is available.

If  I install Ubuntu to the efi boot partition , will windows keep working ?

Comment: /dev/sda is your  hard-disk /dev/sda1 is one of the partition in /dev/sda.I think it was better,if you upload gparted screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Some EFIs support switching between BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode and EFI/UEFI-mode booting in their boot managers. This is a bit awkward, because it usually requires pressing Esc or a function key during a very brief window of time early in the boot process, but it can work acceptably for some people.

If that's not an option, you might try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Try the USB flash drive version first; you can try it without writing anything to disk, then if it works, install it to your hard disk. You'll need to edit the `refind.conf` file, though: Uncomment the `scanfor` option and ensure that `hdbios` is among the options. This will tell rEFInd to scan for BIOS-mode boot options and present any that it finds on its menu. (The default on PCs is to ignore BIOS/CSM/legacy boot options.) Using rEFInd in this way works on many new PCs, but it's not guaranteed to work; some EFIs lack the necessary features, and systems with multiple hard disks don't always work correctly when booting in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I finally decided to let go of UEFI and installed everything in Legacy BIOS mode